# nexus 5 shared internet connection

Tags: nexus-5, internet, wifi-tethering

I try to share my internet connection from my nexus 5 to my computer (on ubuntu).
So I enabled wifi hotspot on my phone bu following http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/01/25/how-to-use-the-nexus-5-as-a-personal-hotspot/ but it doenst work.

The connection between my computer and my phone is working but when I tried to connect to google the connection fail.

I installed tcpdump (by cross-compiling it) and I can see the SYN packet(but there is no SYN ACK) on the wlan0 interface but not on rmnet0(which is the interface where is my internet connection) so I guess it is a routing problem.

routing is enabled:

```
root@hammerhead:/ # cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward                          
1
```

the interfaces :

```
root@hammerhead:/ # ip link | grep UP                                          
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
2: rmnet0: <UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
21: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
```

the route table:

```
10.8.91.76/30 dev rmnet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.91.77 
172.20.2.10 via 10.8.91.78 dev rmnet0  src 10.8.91.77 
172.20.2.39 via 10.8.91.78 dev rmnet0  src 10.8.91.77 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.43.1 


root@hammerhead:/ # ip route
A.A.A.B/30 dev rmnet0  proto kernel  scope link  src A 
172.20.2.10 via 10.8.91.78 dev rmnet0  src 10.8.91.77 
172.20.2.39 via 10.8.91.78 dev rmnet0  src 10.8.91.77 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.43.1
```

the firewall :

```
root@hammerhead:/ # iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
bw_INPUT   all  --  anywhere             anywhere
fw_INPUT   all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
oem_fwd    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
fw_FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
bw_FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
natctrl_FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
oem_out    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
fw_OUTPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
bw_OUTPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain bw_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain bw_INPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! quota globalAlert: 2097152 bytes
bw_costly_rmnet0  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner socket exists

Chain bw_OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! quota globalAlert: 2097152 bytes
bw_costly_rmnet0  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner socket exists

Chain bw_costly_rmnet0 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
bw_penalty_box  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! quota rmnet0: 9223372036854775807 bytes  reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain bw_costly_shared (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
bw_penalty_box  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain bw_happy_box (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain bw_penalty_box (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner UID match u0_a14 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain fw_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fw_INPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fw_OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain natctrl_FORWARD (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain natctrl_tether_counters (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain oem_fwd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain oem_out (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

do you know why it doens't work.
Also when i do `ping 8.8.8.8` from my phone all is working but i don't understand why : there is no default route so how can it decide where to go? can you explain?

thank you

Comment: Thank your for your answer but it doesn't work.

    `# route add default gw 8.8.8.8 dev rmnet0` give me `Network is unreachable`

Comment: oh yes of course sorry. I executed `route add default gw 8.8.8.8 dev wlan0` (wlan0 of the computer) but i have the same error which is quite logical. I think there is no problem on the configuration of the computer because when I try `telnet 8.8.8.8 53` the SYN packet can be read from the wlan0 interface of the phone. The problem is it doesn't go to the rmnet0 (it seems it is not forwarded).

Comment: Do you have tethering on your cell plan? Otherwise, the built-in hotspot probably won't work.

Comment: (Also, to understand routing on the phone you'll have to look at `ip rule`; there is more than one routing table. `ip route list table X` to look at a different one, where X is a table number which you'll see in the `ip rule` output. Look up Linux policy routing for an explanation.)